# Ie8 angularjs triggers all ng-click events in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

So, I'm making an application and it needs to work in IE8. I have several ng-repeats on lists with buttons. In modern browsers, everything works, but in old trash like IE8, it doesn't. When I press one button in IE8, it triggers all the ng-click events. (It needs to add users to a list)

I can't make a jsfiddle of it, but I can give you an example:

```
<table>
<!--list 1-->
<tr ng-repeat="grp in tempUsersToSelect">
<td><button  ng-click="addAllUsers(grp)">{{grp.name}}</button></td></tr>
<!--list 2--> 
<tr id="user {{user.Id}}" ng-repeat="user in allUsersToSelect"><td>{{user.FullName}}</td>
<td><input ng-change="addUser(user)" class="nameBox" type="checkbox" ng-model="addedUsers[user.Id]"/></td></tr> 
</table>
```

I hope anyone of you can see what's wrong. If you have a solution or a remark, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: can you replicate the issue in a plunker so people can test? Also please show your JS code (the relevant parts).

Comment: It is not possible because it is on a website where you first have to log in. I "resolved" the issue with jquery. thanks for the reply